# How to insert WHERE statement in this stored procedure?

Tags: sql

For WHERE statement in tblProducts with actual data from database.
For my problem, I want to add   `WHERE PCategoryID='1'`

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_BindAllProducts]
AS
SELECT A.*, B.*,C.Name, A.PPrice-A.PSelPrice AS DiscAmount,  
       B.Name AS ImageName, C.Name AS BrandName 
FROM tblProducts A
   INNER JOIN tblBrands C ON C.BrandID = A.PBrandID
CROSS APPLY(
   SELECT TOP 1 * 
   FROM tblProductImages B 
   WHERE B.PID = A.PID 
   ORDER BY B.PID DESC
)B
ORDER BY A.PID DESC
```

Comment: Where is the C# or ASP.NET in this question? Please take the [tour] and read [ask] for tips on asking questions that won't be downvoted.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is very product specific.)

Comment: Side note (if you're using **SQL Server**): you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 0):

You should add it just before last `ORDER BY` statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.*, B.*,C.Name, A.PPrice-A.PSelPrice AS DiscAmount,  
       B.Name AS ImageName, C.Name AS BrandName 
FROM tblProducts A
   INNER JOIN tblBrands C ON C.BrandID = A.PBrandID
CROSS APPLY(
   SELECT TOP 1 * 
   FROM tblProductImages B 
   WHERE B.PID = A.PID 
   ORDER BY B.PID DESC
)B
WHERE PCategoryID='1'
ORDER BY A.PID DES
```

You may need to add the correct table alias eg `A.PCategoryID` if the column exists in both tables